# Кастомные сообщения в laravel : указать невалидное значение

Tags: laravel, валидация

Читаю кастомные сообщения в laravel 5.4:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-error-messages.

Можно ли кроме имени поля указать и его невалидное значения?
Что-то вроде:

```
$messages = [
    'unique' => "The :attribute ':value' has already been taken",
    'required' => "The ':attribute' field is required.",
];

$validator = Validator::make( $dataArray , $rules, $messages );
...
```

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? Все заполненые поля и так перед глазами.

Answer (score 0):

Есть способ обхода, на [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/form-validation-custom-error-message-with-input-value?page=0) форуме

namespace App\Services;

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator as BaseValidator;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class CustomValidator extends BaseValidator
{
    protected function validateUniqueName($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        // make use of parent validator validateUnique method.
        return $this->validateUnique($attribute, $value, $parameters);
    }

    protected function replaceUniqueName($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        // parent class $data attribute contains all the validated values.
        $name = Arr::get($this->data, $attribute);
        return str_replace([':value'], [$name], $message);
    }
}
```

и затем в AppServiceProvider:

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new \App\Services\CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
        });
```